# Track Gnosis Safes Created from Specific Source

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

we are using the safe API to create safes for our users and we want to track things like safes created, ETH volume, erc20/NFTs owned in the safe, etc. through platforms like Dune. We aren't using any custom smart contracts at this time, just leveraging Gnosis Safe SDK APIs and service APIs

Is there anyway to do this and isolate that it was our platform that created the safe? For example, maybe calling the API in such a way a custom event is emitted from the smart contract with a "{source}_{version}" that we can just look for through Dune.

If not, is there some other way to track safe activity of our specific platform without having to roll a custom dashboard? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to create your own Gnosis Safes factory contract that stores new safes info that creates on-chain.

Example like this.

```
import "contracts/GnosisSafes.sol";

contract GnosisSafesFactory {
  address[] _safes;

  event SafesCreated(...);

  create() {
     GnosisSafes safes = new GnosisSafes(...some_args);
     
     address.push(address(safes));

     emit SafesCreated(...some_args);
  }
}
```